# Cannot get file to load correctly into jtable

Tags: java, swing, file, split, jtable

I have tried the various answers to load a file into a jtable and I get the same result. I have tried writing the file differently with a "\n" after each cell. When I read it back in all data loads in the first row. What am I doing wrong. I screwed with this the past couple of days.

Text file:
2019-07-31|Car|Car Payment| 330| | 1000|
2019-07-25|Utility Company|Utility| 120| | 880|
2019-07-23|Insurance|Car Insurance| 60| | |

I have 5 columns "Date" "Payee" "Category" "Debit" "Credit" "Balance".
When the data loads into the Jtable I end up with:

"Date" "Payee" "Category" "Debit" "Credit" "Balance".
   2     0        1         9        -         0
Filling 3 rows.

Thank you

```
saveBtn.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
  BufferedWriter bfw = null;
  try {
    bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));

    for (int i = 0; i < accountTbl.getRowCount(); i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < accountTbl.getColumnCount(); j++) {
        bfw.write((String) (accountTbl.getValueAt(i, j)));
        bfw.write("|");
      }
      bfw.newLine();
    }

  } catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    try {
      bfw.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
});


private void loadData() {

String line;
BufferedReader reader;
try {
  reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    model.addRow(line.split("|"));
  }
  reader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: I get 2 0 1 9 - 0 filling 3 rows

Comment: The text file line breaks after 6 "|"

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data for the table.